# Problema modificando título de Archive en Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

para un proyecto he creado un par de custom post types para crear post que son de formación y post que son de descargas.

Luego me pidieron que en la cabecera de los archivos eliminase el title del sitio web de la misma, siendo para poner un ejemplo: Formación - Peluquería Alvarez, expertos en cosmética, dejarlo solo en Formación.

He revisado el template para ver si puedo cambiar eso y me encuentro un do_action() a una función que llama a un framework que llama a otra página de theme_functions y todo esto cuando lo paso al child theme hace que se desomorone.

Mi solución ha sido utilizar jquery para borrar el título y luego volver a añadirlo e irremediablemente utilizar el parametro get a mano para traducirlo:

```php
        <?php

    // Listado de idiomas
    // =======================================================================
        $idioma = array(
            'en' => 'Training',        'de' => 'Ausbildung',        'fr' => 'La formation',        'ar' => 'AR',
            'bs' => 'BS',        'bg' => 'BG',        'ca' => 'CA',        'cs' => 'CS',
            'sk' => 'SK',        'cy' => 'CY',        'da' => 'DA',        'el' => 'EL',
            'eo' => 'EO',        'et' => 'ET',        'eu' => 'EU',        'fa' => 'FA',
            'fi' => 'FI',        'ga' => 'GA',        'he' => 'HE',        'hi' => 'HI',
            'hr' => 'HR',        'hu' => 'HU',        'hy' => 'HY',        'id' => 'ID',
            'is' => 'IS',        'it' => 'Formazione',        'ko' => 'KO',        'ku' => 'KU',
            'lv' => 'LV',        'lt' => 'LT',        'mk' => 'MK',        'mt' => 'MT',
            'mn' => 'MN',        'ne' => 'NE',        'nl' => 'NL',        'no' => 'NO',
            'pa' => 'PA',        'pl' => 'PL',        'pt-pt' => 'Formação',     'pt-br' => 'PTBR',
            'qu' => 'QU',        'ro' => 'RO',        'ru' => 'RU',        'sl' => 'SL',
            'so' => 'SO',        'sq' => 'SQ',        'sr' => 'SR',        'sv' => 'SV',
            'ta' => 'TA',        'th' => 'TH',        'tr' => 'TR',        'uk' => 'UK',
            'ur' => 'UR',        'uz' => 'UZ',        'vi' => 'VI',        'yi' => 'YI',
            'zh-hans' => 'ZH-HANS',        'zu' => 'ZU',        'zh-hant' => 'ZH-HANT',
            'ms' => 'MS',        'gl' => 'GL',        'bn' => 'BN'
        );
    // =======================================================================

    ?>

    <script>
    $('.page-title h1').remove();

    <?php 
        foreach($idioma as $idioma => $cadena){
            if($_GET['lang'] == $idioma){ ?>
                $('.page-title').html('<h1><?php echo $cadena; ?></h1>');
        <?php }elseif($_GET['lang'] == 'es' || $_GET['lang'] == ''){?>
                $('.page-title').html('<h1>Formación</h1>');
        <?php }
        }?>

    </script>
```

Esto funciona a medias, ya que cuando me voy a descargas el título que me aparece es formación.

Necesito saber como filtrar eso ya que llevo bastante tiempo buscando información.

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado! He utilizado las funciones get_post_type(get_the_ID()) para averiguar donde me encontraba y lo he pasado por la condición del siguiente modo:

```php
<?php 
    foreach($idioma_formacion as $idioma => $cadena){
        $tipo = get_post_type(get_the_ID());
        if($tipo == 'formacion' && $_GET['lang'] == $idioma){ ?>
            $('.page-title').html('<h1><?php echo $cadena; ?></h1>');
    <?php }elseif($tipo == 'formacion' && $_GET['lang'] == 'es' || $_GET['lang'] == ''){?>
            $('.page-title').html('<h1>Formación</h1>');
    <?php }
    }?>
```

He repetido lo mismo con descargas y listo.